# Adding specific custom fields (images) to post excerpt

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, advanced-custom-fields, excerpt

I am working on a simple user profile archive, using the theme "Atomic Blocks" as a starter theme. I am using one custom post type and several custom post fields to create these user profiles. The Custom Post type "Profile" and the plugin Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to display different content on each "post" to look like a profile of sorts (a profile picutre, a file download, a video embed and short description).

Now I want to add more custom fields to these custom post type excerpts (see below). Mainly the profile pictures.[image: profile archive page],

I managed to create a custom excerpt that displays the profile description ("Profilbeschreibung" in the image above) custom field with this code:

```
function advanced_custom_field_excerpt() {
    global $post;
    $text = get_field('profilbeschreibung');
    if ( '' != $text ) {
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
        $excerpt_length =30; // 30 words
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }

    return apply_filters('the_excerpt', $text);
}
```

Since I am not that experienced with creating custom wordpress functions I am stuck. My main question would be: **Is there any way to achieve displaying a custom field containing an image in each profile excerpt?**

I know that excerpts have a hard time displaying html, so I am not sure.

I looked all over and found nothing for my specific case. I appreciate any insight into what I might have to do or what went wrong. Thanks!

Comment: First - it will work better if you add multiple custom fields. You should have one for the file download, one for the video embed, one for the description. For the image, it's likely that you can use WP's built-in Featured Image functionality. If you can't use that, you can also add a custom field for the image. Once all the data is split up, it's fairly easy to add within your function - inside your `if` statement, at the end, you can get the featured image (or custom field) of the current post and append it to `$text`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @WebElaine! Well thats where I am stuck. I really don't know how. I normally call my custom fields on each individual post (not the excerpt) with something like $abschluss = get_field('abschluss'); and then use them inside the single post template with <?php if( $abschluss ): ?> etc. But for this I really don't know where to start. I do have a custom field for the image already used on the main posts, now I want to display that custom field in the excerpt I quoted in my question. How do I append it to $text?

Comment: Hi @WebElaine, I now managed to display images using [this function](https://jmp.sh/v/bu5XcISbwvvBJRJZNASn). Is this a viable solution or should I be aware of any future shortcomings?

Comment: Couple of suggestions: one, instead of `echo`ing the image, add it to text. If you want the image last, you can just change `echo` to `$text .=` or if you want the image before the text, you can say `$text = (all the image stuff) . $text`.

Comment: Two: instead of saving the image URL you can have ACF save the image ID. This will help you get whatever particular size of image you want (instead of whatever size may have been uploaded as an original) and you'll also get the alt text (important for accessibility). You can use `$foto = wp_get_attachment_image(get_field('profilfoto'), 'thumbnail')` to get all the details, then add the image tag with the src and alt text.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice @WebElaine! I managed to get to this state right now:  [Image link](https://i.imgur.com/ZKZSDpx.png). With Array being the description or another custom field. The problem I have now is: The profile names (on top of the cards) are the original post titles and don't belong to either the custom excerpt or the custom fields I created. How can I display the profile image above the title in this case? Or add the post title to my custom excerpt? With your suggestions I could display the image below everything, but I haven't managed to display it above.

Comment: At this point it is worth either updating your question with the current code and current question - or creating a new question entirely - so that when other searchers find your question it's clearer what the question was and what the final solution became.